# Background Substraction c# emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I start my adventure with emguCV. I want to write a simple algorithm to detect moving objects. I try to subtract the background but the image is all black.

```
public Form1()
{
   previous = grabber.QueryFrame();
   Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber27);
}

void FrameGrabber27(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Image<Bgr, Byte> output = new Image<Bgr,Byte>(300,300);
   Image<Bgr, Byte> actual = grabber.QueryFrame();

   int width = output.Width;
   int height = output.Height;

   image27.Image = grabber.QueryFrame();
   ibProcessed.Image = actual;
   for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
       {                       
           if ((actual[j, i].Blue == previous[j, i].Blue) && ( actual[j, i].Red == previous[j, i].Red)&&(actual[j, i].Green == previous[j, i].Green))                    
           {
               output[j, i] =newBgr(0,0,0);                             
           }
           else
           {                         
               output[j, i] = new Bgr(255, 255, 255);
           }
       }
   }
   im.Image = output;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why do you set the size of the output Image to 300*300 and not to actual.width*actual.height?
2. `output[j, i] =newBgr(0,0,0);` I hope that in your project you didn't forget the space?
3. `((actual[j, i].Blue == previous[j, i].Blue) && ( actual[j, i].Red == previous[j, i].Red)&&(actual[j, i].Green == previous[j, i].Green))` This will return almost always true as even if the webcam and the scene are statics, there will always be very slight changes of color on every pixels between two frames.
4. OpenCV offers 2 functions for background subtraction: [Here it is](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/947e83c8-ab88-c8ce-6a89-41235860d12a.htm)